# loop through listfield in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need some help to create a loop through a listfield.

listfield:

```
lstPlanung
```

function:

```
Dim i As Integer

     For i = 0 To Me!lstPlanung.ListCount - 1

             Me!lstPlanung.Selected(i) = True
             Call sendemailKunde

     Next i
```

Is it possible to modify the loop that it selects every entry of my listfield?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are already looping on every entry in the list. What else do you want to do ?

Comment: i want to select entry by entry and call a function for each selected entry in my listfield. but it seems to me that the loop isnt working correct because the output that i get matches only the first entry of my listbox.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear.

Is it this you are trying to do ?

```
Dim i As Integer
dim strFoo as string 

 For i = 0 To Me!lstPlanung.ListCount - 1

         ' Get the current listbox item in the loop
         strFoo  = Me.lstPlanung.ItemData(i)

         Call sendemailKunde

 Next i
```

With this, `strFoo` will contain the element of your listbox at each iteration in your loop. But you have to do something with it...